# Localization using CultureInfo - punctuation marks

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, localization

I use CultureInfo in order to localize my application:

```
CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
```

I encountered a problem that has to do with punctuation marks:
In my local database (from which I'm getting all the useful data for my app) the Latitude and Longitude properties are stored with dots (i.e. 45.245135) and that's fine when CultureInfo is set to en-US. However, when I switch to my native language (where the dot is perceived as a thousand mark) none of my map functions can work.

I'd be too difficult if I was to change each bit of my code that handles these values, it's everywhere more or less.

Any ideas on solving that?

Comment: Storing numbers as strings in a dbase is a Really Bad Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try working with `InvariantCulture` whenever you convert to/from `String`:

```
  String stLattitude = "45.245135";
  ... 
  // String to Double
  // Culture.InvariantCulture make the conversion Culture independent
  Double lattitude = Double.Parse(stLattitude, Culture.InvariantCulture);
  ...
  // Double To String
  // Culture.InvariantCulture make the conversion Culture independent
  String strLattitude = lattitude.ToString(Culture.InvariantCulture);
```

Use `CurrentCulture` only when you're showing the final result to user

```
  // Showing to user: that's why CurrentCulture (default) is used
  Show(lattitude.ToString());
```